# Paginated list of group members

Tags: 8, group

I want to output the membership of a drupal group, but limiting the number of members shown, instead of outputting all members at once, (that i can do with the code bellow).

```
    $members = $group->getContentEntities('group_membership');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to build an entity query for the group members you can use `$query->pager()`. See [block to display nodes using entityQuery with pager](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232643/block-to-display-nodes-using-entityquery-with-pager)

If not, you have to calculate the pager variables yourself. There is only one example for a pager in core that is not using a pager query, the taxonomy terms overview [OverviewTerms::buildForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Form%21OverviewTerms.php/function/OverviewTerms%3A%3AbuildForm/8.3.x). Or you can use [pager_default_initialize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/8.3.x).

And a third and probably quickest solution is to build a view for the group members.

Comment: I cold do something like this: 

    `\Drupal::entityQuery('group_content')
          ->condition('gid', $group->id())
          ->condition('type', "{$bundle}-group_membership")
          ->range(0, 4)
              ->execute();` 
    
but can i pass without the bundle? I only want the membership.

Comment: I don't have the module group installed, but can't you just use only the 'gid' condition?. Instead of range() use pager(), so that you can use the built in pager element.

Comment: group_content returns both the users and the associated nodes, so i must specify what i want. I was hoping there was some way to avoid it.